# Is there a simple way of using XXXutil.exe?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I keep reading that I have to use svcUtil.exe, crmSvcUtil.exe and company with tons of parameters.

What I've been told is to use the command prompt, but this takes forever to type and returns errors most of the time.

Is there a simple way to use those executables? Something that, at least, supports copy/paste? And, of course, return clearly and precisely what is wrong instead of just doing nothing.

Thank you!

Comment: Erm, if it "returns errors most of the time", how is not clear and precise about what is wrong?  If the errors don't mean anything to you then RTFM or ask a SO question about it.  The command console supports copy/paste, click on the system menu (upper left icon).

Comment: This time, for instance, I use crmSvcUtil and it returns no error, it just show the help and does nothing else whenever I send a command. How am I suppose to find what's wrong? Thx for the copy/paste hint, didn't see it.

Comment: The command line you gave it is wrong.  No way to guess what you did wrong, you didn't document it.  Ask a real question.

Comment: Can you post the command you are sending so we can help?

Comment: Thank you for offering, but that would be out of the scope of this more general question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my conclusion is:

- There is no simpler way of using those utilities (no wizard or other facilitator)
- To debug the utility, the best best is to look again and again and, if you can't find the error, ask someone
- Command prompt supports copy/paste through the top left menue of the command window

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

1) Open up a text editor and type in the same line that you would put into the command line

2) Save the file with the .bat extension (say, *myfile.bat*)

3) Open up the command prompt, navigate to where ever you saved the file, and run that file

(i.e. you're making a quick batch script that does nothing else but run your command)

Comment: That's a way to fix part of the problem (typing time), but it doesn't help to find what the problem is.

Comment: Like the others have said, we can't help figure that out without seeing the command you're trying to use.